I don't know what a dispersion parameter is in a binomial regression
I'm currently doing my undergraduate thesis project and i'm about to start analyzing the results of my regressions but i don't understand what the dispersion parameter in a binomial regression means.
To be more precise, i've searched around and from what i understand the dispersion parameter in a binomial regression should be always a fixed 1. But in my binomial regressions it's way more than that. As you can see below. the dispersion parameter is taken to be  "429264.1", Is this normal?
enter image description here
I did another binomial regression but with a logit link instead or a probit one and the dispersion parameter changed to a lower number but it is still larger than 1. It is "367.2509"
enter image description here
What am i missing here? Is this something to worry about?
I tried to use different types of binomial regressions, like logit and probit, i also searched a little online but it is too difficult for me to completely understand the statistics and formulas behind it.
Thanks for the help.
